# How to use a WHERE clause for a query in an influx database?

Tags: sql, influxdb

I want to make a query in an influx database to select entries which have a status unequal to 200.

I tried the following:

```
select * from http_reqs where status!=200 limit 30;
select * from http_reqs where "status"!=200 limit 30;
```

Here I get no result.

```
select * from http_reqs where status!="200" limit 30;
select * from http_reqs where "status"!="200" limit 30;
```

Here I get ALL results (even the entries which have status=200)

What am I doing wrong?

Also, the following query does not return anything:

```
select status from http_reqs limit 300;
```

I am confused.

However, the following query returns something

```
select * from http_reqs limit 300;
```

it returns 300 entries with the following header:

```
time error error_code method name proto scenario status tls_version type url value
```

Comment: What is the data type of `status`?  If it is a string, you might have hidden characters, such as spaces.  If your query with no `where` returns nothing, then your table is empty.

Comment: Never mind, I did query ALL of the data, put that into a file, and use a python script to do the actual query. Much easier that this crap

Comment: @GordonLinoff `status` seems to be a string without hidden characters, as the python script to select entries from  that SQL query just works fine.

Answer (score 2):

InfluxDB is not crap. You just need to learn it - it is not a SQL database! I bet your `status` is tag, so it really doesn't make sense to use only tag in the SELECT part. I guess it is also a string type, so correct query syntax should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM http_reqs 
WHERE "status"!='200'
LIMIT 30
```

Don't blame me if it is not working, because it is almost blind guess. You didn't provide your measurement structure (fields/tags and their types).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to work! So the kind of quotation is important here (single quotes vs. double quotes)? Also, what do you mean by `measurement structure`?

Comment: @Alex Quick transition guide from SQL mind to InfluxDB mind (but it isn't 1:1 mapping, always read InfluxDB doc): `table` -> `measurement`, `column which can be aggregated with aggregation function` -> `field`, `column which can be used for filtering, grouping` -> `tag`, column definition in the where section should be in the `""` and text value in `''`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the "status" feature is not entirely int, it seems to have a mix of int and chars. Try typecasting the feature to int and then use it in the query.

Comment: I cannot even do the following query: `select status from http_reqs  limit 3;` I get zero results!

Comment: Or this query: `select "method" from http_reqs  limit 3;`

Comment: And here I get an error: `select 'method' from http_reqs  limit 3;`